# Typo3 vhs language returns id instead of language

Tags: typo3

I try to setup a language menu with 3 different languages. For english and german its working. It shows the current language either as EN or DE. But when i switch to italian, it only shows the id (7) in the frontend.

My Code is:

`{v:page.language(languages: 'EN,DE,IT', pageUid: '0', normalWhenNoLanguage: 'EN')`

Lanugage setup:

```
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
    config {
        sys_language_uid = 1
        language = de
        locale_all = de_DE.UTF-8
        htmlTag_setParams = lang="de" dir="ltr" class="no-js"
    }
[global]

[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
    config {
        sys_language_uid = 2
        language = fr
        locale_all = fr_FR.UTF-8
        htmlTag_setParams = lang="fr" dir="ltr" class="no-js"
    }
[global]

[globalVar = GP:L = 7]
    config {
        sys_language_uid = 7
        language = it
        locale_all = it_IT.UTF-8
        htmlTag_setParams = lang="it" dir="ltr" class="no-js"
    }
[global]
```

Comment: is it possible that the language-record is disabled or has another title than `IT`? Also check the language setup if everything is correct.

Comment: its not disabled and i added the setup

Answer (score 0):

If the id is 7 and your array of languages only contains three elements, what do you expect?

The VH does not access the TS configuration. It can't as the VH can not influence conditions to select the 'requested' language. So it only can access the **current** language configuration.

The 8th element of three elements (= your first parameter to this VH: the array with the 2 character language codes) would be out of range and should not be accessed (and if you do as it is possible in some languages you get an security issue).

Comment: i expect it to show the language as for the other two examples.
for english i get -> EN, for german -> DE and for italian -> 7?! it has the id 7 on root level, but i want to display the language code as for the other languages

Comment: @tim: why do you expect that the value 7 should be result in `languages[2]` (languages[] = first parameter of VH)? Have a look at the [source of this VH](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/vhs/blob/master/Classes/ViewHelpers/Page/LanguageViewHelper.php).

Comment: i dont expect 7. i expect "IT" for italian"

Comment: i only have 3 languages (0) default english (1) german and (7) italian. would this mean i need to add blanks in the list? `{v:page.language(languages: 'EN,DE,2,3,4,5,6,IT', pageUid: '0', normalWhenNoLanguage: 'EN')}`